# Split rdd and access subgroup of elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I would like to split my RDD regarding commas and access a predefined set of elements.

For example, I have a RDD like that:

```
a, b, c, d
e, f, g, h
```

and I need to split then access the first and fourth element on the first line and the second and third element on the second line to get this resulting RDD:

```
a, d
f, g
```

I can't hard write "1" and "4" on my code, that's why solution like that won't work:

```
rdd.map{line => val words = line.split(",") (words(0),words(3)) }
```

Lets assume I have a second RRD with the same number of lines which contains the elements I want to get for each line

```
1,4
2,3
```

Is there a way to get my elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lets assume I have a second RRD with the same number of lines which contains the elements I want to get for each line

```
1,4
2,3
```

> Is there a way to get my elements ?

If you have a second RDD that already has the numbers of the groups you want for each line, you could zip them.
From Spark docs:

```
<U> RDD<scala.Tuple2<T,U>> zip(RDD<U> other, scala.reflect.ClassTag<U> evidence$13)
```

> Zips this RDD with another one, returning key-value pairs with the first element in each RDD, second element in each RDD, etc.

So in your example, `a, b, c, d` would be in a key-value pair with `1,4` and `e, f, g, h` with `2,3` . So you could do something like:

```
val groupNumbers = lettersRDD zip numbersRDD

groupnumbers.map{tuple -> 
val numbers: Seq[Int] = // get the numbers from tuple._2
 val words = tuple._1.split(",") (words(numbers.head),words(numbers(1) ) }
}
```